# Application of properties of the exterior derivative to show submersion is preserved by translations by constant.

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

Let $p \in M$ be a smooth manifold and let $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, and let it further be known that $df|_p$ is surjective for all $p \in M$ such that $f(p) = 0$. Now, am I correct in identifying the tangent-map $df$ with the exterior derivative $d: \Omega^{n}(M) \to \Omega^{n+1}(M)$ applied to $f$, and can I use this to say that since $d$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, then it follows that if $df|_p$ is a submersion, then $dg|_p$ is a submersion, where $g = f-c$, since by $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of $d$, we have that $$dg = d(f-c) = df-dc = df.$$ I think one can see that $dc = 0$ most simply by viewing $dc$ as a smooth constant function on $M$ and then using local coordinates to see that since it is constant, it will just vanish.

This question is asked in the context of the *regular value theorem* (I think it is called). So one can then use this to say that $f$ is a locally defining function on a neighborhood $V$ around each point $p \in M$ such that $f(p)-c = 0 \iff f(p) = c$. I.e. we have $f|_V:V \to \mathbb{R}$ (our submersion) and the set $N_c = \{p \in M| f(p) = c\}$ is a submanifold of codimension $1$, where (by another theorem) for $p \in N_c$,  $$T_pN_c = \operatorname{ker}dg|_p = \operatorname{ker}df|_p = \operatorname{ker} \langle \operatorname{grad}f(p),- \rangle = (\operatorname{grad}f(p))^{\perp}.$$

So my most important question is basically if I can justify $dg = df$ because of the $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of the exterior derivative?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You do not need to think about $f$ as a $0$-form and $d$ as the exterior derivative. It follows from the definition of the derivative of a map.

Comment: @TedShifrin You mean by using the fact that $T_pf$ is a linear map? I was trying that at first but something  did not click. I mean yes, it is the case that $T_pg = T_p(f-c) = T_pf-T_pc?$ And now $T_pc$ vanishes so we are left  with $T_pf$.

Comment: Yes, of course, Ben. Indeed, it is more general. If, for example, $f\colon M\to N\subset\Bbb R^n$ and it happens that for some $c\in\Bbb R^n$, $N+c\subset N$, then $g=f+c$ also maps $M$ to $N$ and $df_p = dg_p$ for all $p\in M$. (I grant that this seems a bit artificial. But ...)

Comment: Yeah, I don´t know why that did not click at first, it is entirely obvious that it must be the case now (not your latest statement, but your first statement).